# How to get rid of `> run | debug` clickable text?

Tags: lsp, rust

I want to get rid of the arrow and the run/debug clickable option (I'm fine with my shortcuts, I never use the mouse and it just gets in the way) but I've no idea what it's called and googling various things doesn't enlighten me.

Any idea either how to disable this, or at least to find out what's providing it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VSCode calls them “lenses” for whatever reason, so you can customize them with `M-x customize-group lsp-rust-analyzer-lens`.